# css with curved line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
OldFunc = window.onload;
window.onload = OnLoad;

function OnLoad() {
    try {
        OnFixFontAndTable();
        OldFunc();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

function OnFixFontAndTable() {
    $('.something some').css({
        'behavior': 'url(/path/border-radius.htc)'
    });
}
```

I am using `border-radius.htc` to fix the the issue with previous version of IEs,
but the `alert(e)` is always called as `"TypeError:Object expected"`.

Comment: IMO is not worth the trouble for something as trivial as border-radius...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `defer="defer"` in your `script` tag like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: Oh thank you  but how can I add that word "defer" at runtime ?

Comment: don't you have script tag on your page

Comment: @TheosArtise - `scriptTag.setAttribute("defer","defer");`

Comment: Like this that I can only write external js to do this, I can't edit source. There is a command for me to add the above script file into the page that runs it

Comment: @TheosArtise - It is a reference to your script tag (you have to somehow target the script tag yourself, either using `var scriptTag = $("script")` or `var scriptTag = document.querySelector("script")`.)